# Video cropping with FFMpeg on Android is very slow

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg

**What i tried:**

I am trying to implement video cropping on android using FFMpeg ([ffmpeg-android](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android))).

Here is the command I use:

```
String[] complexCommand = {"-i", inputPath, "-strict", "experimental", "-vf", "crop=1080:1080:0:0", "-threads", "5", "-c:v", "libx264", "-preset", "ultrafast", filePath};
```

**The problem:**

Video cropping is working, but even though I am using all needed options to make the operation fast, it still takes a 1min long video the same duration to crop.

How can I achieve better speeds?
Will I need to implement video cropping on server instead of device?
 
Is there another way to implement video cropping on Android instead of FFMpeg?

I understand that I can achieve better UX by letting the user edit a cropped TextureView/SurfaceView while doing the actual cropping in background, but I want to avoid this way as it takes more time.

**UPDATE**

Here is FFMpeg's log output:

```
SUCCESS with output : ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
    built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
    configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
    libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
    libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
    libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
    libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
    libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
    libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
    libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
    libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
    Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/MOV_0066.mp4':
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2017-04-02 11:58:58
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
    Duration: 00:00:59.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 17759 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080, 17498 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 29.90 fps, 29.92 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    rotate          : 90
    creation_time   : 2017-04-02 11:58:58
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
    Side data:
    displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 155 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-04-02 11:58:58
    handler_name    : SoundHandle
    [libx264 @ 0xb5bc4400] using SAR=1/1
    [libx264 @ 0xb5bc4400] using cpu capabilities: none!
    [libx264 @ 0xb5bc4400] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 3.2, 4:2:0 8-bit
    [libx264 @ 0xb5bc4400] 64 - core 148 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2015 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x1 me=dia subme=1 psy=0 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=0 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=5 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc=cqp mbtree=0 qp=0
    Output #0, mp4, to '/storage/emulated/0/Download/compress_video1.mp4':
    Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 6.0.1
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1080x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 29.92 fps, 11488 tbn, 29.92 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandle
    creation_time   : 2017-04-02 11:58:58
    encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 libx264
    Side data:
    unknown side data type 10 (24 bytes)
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2017-04-02 11:58:58
    handler_name    : SoundHandle
    encoder         : Lavc57.24.102 aac
    Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
    Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
    frame=    6 fps=0.0 q
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to show the complete console output/log from your command. It will contain useful info and may show what the actual issue is (such as not properly using CPU capabilities).

Comment: I updated my answer and noticied this line "using cpu capabilities: none!". How can I fix this?

Comment: I have never (cross-)compiled for ARM, so I don't know specifics. You need to recompile x264: do not use the `--disable-asm` configure option, and the output after you run `./configure` should show `asm: yes`. Do not proceed if it says `no`. Also, use a recent version of x264–if I recall correctly there are some improvements for your CPU since your old version. Then you'll need to recompile ffmpeg to use to your new x264. Ensure that it links to the proper x264 if there are multiple versions on your system.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use lesser resolution
2. Use server-size cropping if you have got a good server. Remember not always have got good internet connection.
3. FFMPEG if rather fast. Make you concept better.